# Is it possible to name streets or neighbourhoods?

Tags: simcity-2013

In SimCity 4, I loved personalising my city by naming streets, building and neighbourhoods. Is this feature present in 2013 incarnation of SimCity?

Comment: it doesn't appear to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. I have had a good route through the menu's and it seems that this feature (along with many others) is not present in SimCity 2013